# WSO2 APIMPattern 3 Deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

```
[2024-03-08 05:36:39,176]  WARN - InboundHttpServerWorker Could not get tenant configuration context for tenant jivatest.com. Tenant may not exist. Message will be dispatched to super tenant.
[2024-03-08 05:36:39,201]  INFO - LogMediator {inboundendpoint:SecureWebhookServer} STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /t/jivatest.com/v1.1/activities/v1.1/123, HEALTH CHECK URL = /t/jivatest.com/v1.1/activities/v1.1/123
[2024-03-08 05:36:41,390]  WARN - MiscellaneousUtil Error loading properties from a file at from the System defined location: access-log.properties
```

Able to generate token , In gateway getting invalid url.

Created oob apis without tenant, Still its failing there also.

`Control_plane` is not connecting with gateway

Comment: When you deploy an API, do you see the relevant logs in the gateway?

Comment: This while consuming apis

Comment: 2024-03-08T11:50:29.975743094Z [2024-03-08 11:50:29,974]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[2024-03-08 11:50:29,974]  INFO - PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener HTTPS Reloaded
[2024-03-08 11:54:36,112] ERROR - APIUtil Error while creating axis configuration for tenant jivatest.com
2024-03-08T11:54:36.200613898Z java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while getting tenant activation status.
2024-03-08T11:54:36.200632473Z  at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:126) ~

Comment: Created without tenant same behavior ,persist there also .

Comment: If the API is not deployed in the gateway properly you won't be able to consume it.

Comment: Created and published apis through publisher portal and how to make sure its deployed in gateway or not ?

Comment: You would see some logs in the gateway if the API is deployed properly. If its not there, that means theres a connectivity issue between gw and cp

Comment: Whatever logs i had posted above is from gateway and not from control plane